# sharepoint 2010 changing email from address to something meaningful

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alert

When I create an alert to send email, the from address in my outlook looks like this: Institute

Institute is the list that triggered the email. I know I can change the email from in Central Admin, but can I change the [Institute] piece to be something meaningful? This email goes out to the Board of Directors and if they receive an email from `Institute <Admin@MyCompany.org>` they delete it becuase it doesnt make sense to them.

Comment: Would something as simple as changing the list name do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

You might could modify this by implementing your own AlertNotifyHandler and override the OnNotification method to modify the SPAlertHandlerParams.Headers["from"] value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spalerthandlerparams.headers.aspx